# How to display different sections of JSON values using Jquery with breadcrumbs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have implemented a questionnaire which navigates through different sections when 'next' button is clicked. Those values are dynamically pulled from JSON and displayed.

I have breadcrumbs(made in HTML) in my site which should take through different sections though clicked randomly without using 'Next' button.

as sections[0],sections[1],etc.. from JSON.

I added

```
     nav:function(){    
            this.sectionPointer=3;
                }
```

and  in HTML. This directly loads the third section when refreshed without click event.

Please help

Here is my code..

```
     var xComponent = {
        sectionPointer:0,
        initControls:function(){
        $("#nextSecBtn").mouseup(function(){
                xComponent.sectionPointer++;
                xComponent.getX();
            });},


     getX:function(){
     $.getJSON("ajax/X.json",function(data){
    xComponent.createDOM(data);
     });
     },


     CreateDOM:function(json){      
     var currentSectionData = json.sections[this.sectionPointer];

     // value pulled from JSON to display in HTML format
     },

 JSON code:
         "sections": [
          {
           "slabel": "How",
           "questions": [
              {
              "seqNum": "1",
               "qtext": "What level ?",
              "fieldtype": "slider1",
              "mcoptions": [1,2,3]
               },
             {question2,3..}]
             },
             {section 2,3...}
            ///goes section 2,3,etc.. which holds set of questions &fields.
```

HTML breadcrumb:

```
        <ul class="breadcrumb">            
        <li><a href="" id="sec1"> How you Develop</a></li>
        <li><a href="" id="sec2"> How you Test</span></a></li></ul>
```

Thank you so much in advance...

Comment: Can you provide an example of the json data returned from ajax/X.json and the html for the page?

Comment: Please `edit` your question (use the link above) don't add code to the comment section.

Comment: @Smith - I have updated the JSON format and html in my question.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? Note that you'll want to replace my `mockJSON` with the actual json returned from your `$.getJSON` call. However if you take this code exactly as it is, using the mock data you'll see that clicking the breadcrumb links will make use of your `xComponent` object to parse the json for section and question values and render them on the page.

Also I put the Next button back, clicking on it will advance to the next section as well. When the page loads it will default to the first section. And lastly I've added css and put in some code to adjust the class set on the active section link.

Is this what you had in mind? I believe I've addressed all the items in your initial question as well as the follow up requests you've added. This should be enough to answer your question and if you run into more problems later perhaps you should start a new question after you've incorporated these changes into your work.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var mockJSON = {
      "sections": [
        {
         "slabel": "Section 1",
         "questions": [
            {
              "seqNum": "1",
              "qtext": "Section 1 quesiton 1 is... ?",
              "fieldtype": "slider1",
              "mcoptions": [1,2,3]
            },
            {
              "seqNum": "2",
              "qtext": "Section 1 question 2 is...?",
              "fieldtype": "slider1",
              "mcoptions": [1,2,3]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
         "slabel": "Section 2",
         "questions": [
            {
              "seqNum": "1",
              "qtext": "Section 2 question 1 is... ?",
              "fieldtype": "slider1",
              "mcoptions": [1,2,3]
            },
            {
              "seqNum": "2",
              "qtext": "Section 2 questoin 2 is...?",
              "fieldtype": "slider1",
              "mcoptions": [1,2,3]
            }
          ]
        }]
      };

      var xComponent = {
        sectionPointer:0,
        initControls:function(){
          var _self = this;
          $("#nextSecBtn").click(function(){
                _self.sectionPointer+=1;
                xComponent.getX(_self.sectionPointer);
            });
            //doing this on init in order to show the first section by default initially
            this.getX(this.sectionPointer);
        },
        getX:function(index){
          //commenting this out in place of using mocked up data. you would
          //want to uncomment this to get the json from ajax/X.json
          // $.getJSON("ajax/X.json",function(data){
          //   this.createDOM(data, index);
          // });
          this.createDOM(mockJSON, index);

          //remove active class from all links
          $(".breadcrumb li a").removeClass("active");
          //add active class to the clicked link
          $("#sec" + (this.sectionPointer+1)).addClass("active");
        },
        createDOM:function(json, index){
          console.log("getX:createDOM json",json);
          console.log("getX:createDOM index", index);
          //if the index exceeds the length of the json sections then reset to 0 to start over
          if (index>=json.sections.length){
            index=0;
          }
          this.sectionPointer = index;
          var currentSectionData = json.sections[index];
          console.log("createDOM:currentSectionData", currentSectionData);
          // value pulled from JSON to display in HTML format
          var sectionHTML = "<p>" + currentSectionData.slabel + "</p><p>" + currentSectionData.questions[0].qtext + "</p>";
          $("#sectionContents").css("border","solid 1px").html(sectionHTML);
       }
     };

     $( document ).ready(function() {
        xComponent.initControls();

        $(".breadcrumb li a").each( function( index ) {
          $(this).click( function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            xComponent.getX(index);
          });
        });
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    .breadcrumb {
      background-color: white;
      color: black;
      font-weight: normal;
    }
    .active {
      background: black;
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="#" id="sec1"> How you Develop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="sec2"> How you Test</span></a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="sectionContents"></div>

  <div style="padding-top:3em;"><button id="nextSecBtn" type="button">Next</button></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Smith - Hi, thanks for your suggestion. However, my doubt is I am unable to navigate to different sections with breacrumbs. I added this.sectionpointer=2 or 3 etc.. and called the onlclick function in HTML LI tag. It loads the particular section page directly without click event. Please help.. Thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your feedback. I removed the Next button and made each breadcrumb link call the javascript to parse the corresponding section from the json and display it. Is this more what you had in mind?

Comment: @Smith - Thank you so much Smith, The code worked great... After changing, I dn't get Next button working. The styles of breadcrumb navigation doesn't get applied. and the page when refreshed doesn't display the first section by default. Rather it shows plain section. I have added those code in the edited post. Can you please check if something is wrong? Thanks again

Comment: Please check out my updated answer. I've added the new items you mentioned as far as I understand what you're asking for.